# XML Content Extraction C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq

I am trying to extract the content of the `<str>` tag from :

```
<lst name="Stack">
  <lst name="Overflow">
     <arr name="content">
       <str>Help</str>
     </arr>
  </lst>
</lst>
```

The code I am using in C# is:

```
txtResponse.Text += xDoc.Descendants("lst")
        .Where(f => (string) f.Attribute("name") == "Overflow")
        .Descendants("arr")
        .Descendants("str")
        .Select(b => b.Value);
```

but it returns to me

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,System.String]
```

Whats my problem?

Comment: There is already an answer on your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462349/parsing-xml-content-c-sharp

Comment: The previous question is similar but there are subtle differences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code returns a collection (i.e. enumeration) of elements, not a single one. In your case actually a `IEnumerable<string>`, i.e. "a list of strings". The `Text` property expects a single string.

It is not clear from your question how exactly the content of the `txtResponse` should look like, but you could do something like this.

```
   var result = xDoc.Descendants("lst")
        .Where(f => (string) f.Attribute("name") == "Overflow")
        .Descendants("arr")
        .Descendants("str")
        .Select(b => b.Value);

   txtResponse.Text = string.Join(", ", result);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need just the first record you need just this

```
txtResponse.Text += xDoc.Descendants("lst")
                   .Where(f => (string) f.Attribute("name") == "Overflow")
                   .Descendants("arr")
                   .Descendants("str")
                   .Select(b => b.Value)
                   .FirstorDefault();
```

Comment: '+=' cannot be applied to type 'string' and 'method group' error

Comment: i have just tested this and works fine.